# Disable SSH version info on Telnet

Tags: ssh, telnet, banner

I need to disable SSH information while telnet to SSH port in CentOS.

```
telnet 192.168.10.192 22
Trying 192.168.10.192...
Connected to 192.168.10.192.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
```

Please help!

Comment: Well, you can disable telnet on the server or change the port.

Comment: No he is connecting to the ssh server on port 22 not to a telnet server.

Answer (score 3):

Providing the protocol version is part of the SSH handshake, as can be seen here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2 It cannot be disabled.

Comment: Please anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: You can't. It is a part of the Protocol. SSH won't work without it.